# O que são e quais são as principais diferenças entre pull parsing e push parsing?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, parser

Estava procurando um *parser* para Markdown implementado em Rust e acabei me deparando com dois termos os quais não tenho a mínima familiaridade:

- *pull parsing*
- *push parsing*

Até onde sei são duas técnicas diferentes para se fazer *parse*.

O que são e quais são as principais características de cada um deles?

Comment: A _create_ em questão é [esta](https://crates.io/crates/pulldown-cmark). Tem uma breve descrição lá, mas nada muito esclarecedor. Farei mais algumas pesquisas depois e conforme for até respondo se tiver adquirido informações o suficiente e ninguém ainda tiver respondido. Mas claro que quem quiser responder estará bem-vindo(a). :)